# How to read Data from an Input Box before the User click the Submit Button? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the Data of an Inputbox (Lets say Username) before the usrr even click the Submit button?

Comment: Try to read input box data on textbox change event in jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use jquery for achieve this

suppose your form is like

```
<form id="myForm" action="post">
```

then you can use

```
$(function(){
   $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var username=$('#txtbox').val();
   $("#myForm").submit();
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('#txtbox').on('input', function() {
// code
});
```

OR

```
jQuery('#txtbox').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
// code
});
```